# Sign APK in Android Studio 2.1.1

Tags: apk

Under Build, there is no option of "Generate Signed APK". The only options are Make Module and Deploy Module to APP Engine. What should I do?

I don't know what to do.

Comment: It can be for a lot of factors, we need more information, but why don't you update the Android Studio?

Comment: I just wanna sign my apk to upload into Google Playstore. I'm not so clued up with coding and intend to learn more in the near future.

Comment: We still need more information to help you =/. But I would say that you will be faster if update. Good luck!